# Will normalization provide better scores?

Tags: optimization, normalization, ranking

I'm trying to come up with a decent way of providing suggestions for folders based on documents in a search result. A folder should receive a high score if all of its documents appear in a search result, and the other way around.

What I first did was to score folder by calculating the percent of documents for any given folder that appeared in the search result. A folder with 10 documents and all those document appearing in a search result would receive a 100% score.

The first approach didn't take into account folder size. Folders with 1000 documents in total, and 750 appearing in search results got less scores that folders with 10 documents and 10 appearing in search results.

I'm now trying to normalize the scores (i.e., `(count - min) / (max - min)`):

- count = number of docs in result from any given folder
- min = number of docs in result for the folder that the least number of docs in result appear in
- max = number of docs in result for the folder that the most number of docs in result appear in

This gives me scores on a scale from 0 to 1.

**When I normalize the scores, do I then reduce the impact of folders with 10 of 10 = 100% of documents in search result vs. 750 of 1000 = 75% of documents in search results?** (Ideally I'd like the 75% folder to receive a higher score.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply check for this by calculating for the example you have given.

Supposing $min$ is near $0$ and $max$ near $1000$ which means $points(10)=\frac{10-0}{1000-0}=1\%$ while $points(750)=\frac{750-0}{1000-0}=75\%$

However there are more aspects of this problem of scoring folders based on searches such as the popularity of each file (i.e. how many times it gets found) and popularity of searched term (i.e. how many times a certain term gets searched), and accordingly rank the folders.

Comment: Thanks @ZeroPancakes - it looks obvious when you write it like that :-) Yes, and there's more into ranking folders - but that data isn't something I've got at hand unfortunately so I'll try to piece together a decent suggestion mechanism based on this combined with score boosting for phrase vs. folder name matching.

Comment: @sbrattla Glad I could help